# How to control the format within rf string python?

Tags: python, number-formatting

I would like to control the number of significant digits in a scientific notation. Like instead of having 2.3333333333333333e-07 I need 2.33e-7, within a rf string.

This is the code I have

```
import numpy as np
eta_arr=np.linspace(0.2,0.5,10)*1e-6
legendstr=[rf'$eta={x}$' for x in eta_arr ]

print(legendstr)
```

code output:

```
['$eta=2e-07$', '$eta=2.3333333333333333e-07$', '$eta=2.6666666666666667e-07$', '$eta=3.0000000000000004e-07$', '$eta=3.3333333333333335e-07$', '$eta=3.6666666666666667e-07$', '$eta=4e-07$', '$eta=4.3333333333333335e-07$', '$eta=4.6666666666666666e-07$', '$eta=5e-07$']
```

I tried different combinations like {0.2e x} , {x/0.2e} etc But didn't work.Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

The `:.3` [formatting modifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) seems to do what you want:

```
>>> a = 2.33333333333e-07
>>> rf'$eta={a:.3}'
'$eta=2.33e-07'
```